# asp.net mvc 4 - form submit button not responding

Tags: asp.net-mvc, submit

I am new to MVC and is using MVc4 with VS2013.  This is my controller:

```
 [HttpPost]
 public ActionResult Create(CreateRequestViewModel viewModel)
 {
    if (ModelState.IsValid)
    {
        return RedirectToAction("Index");
    }             
    return View(viewModel);
}
```

Below is my view:

```
@model ProMs.Web.ViewModels.CreateRequestViewModel

@{
    ViewBag.Title = "Create";
}

<body>

    <h2>New Request</h2>
    <h3></h3>
    @using (Html.BeginForm())
    {
        @Html.AntiForgeryToken()
        @Html.ValidationSummary(true)

        <fieldset>

            <div class="float-left">
                <label for="RequestName">Request</label>
                @Html.EditorFor(model => model.Request.RequestName)
                @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Request.RequestName)

                @Html.LabelFor(model => model.Request.Requestor)
                @Html.EditorFor(model => model.Request.Requestor)
                @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Request.Requestor)

                @Html.LabelFor(model => model.Request.Purpose)
                @Html.EditorFor(model => model.Request.Purpose)
                @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Request.Purpose)
            </div>

            <div class="float-right">
                @Html.LabelFor(model => model.Request.Investigator)
                @Html.EditorFor(model => model.Request.Investigator)
                @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Request.Investigator)

                @Html.LabelFor(model => model.Request.Department)
                @Html.EditorFor(model => model.Request.Department)
                @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Request.Stage)

                @Html.LabelFor(model => model.Request.Comment)
                @Html.EditorFor(model => model.Request.Comment)
                @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Request.Comment)                
            </div>

            @Html.HiddenFor(model => model.Request.RequestID)
            @Html.HiddenFor(model => model.Request.DateCreated)
            @Html.HiddenFor(model => model.Request.CreatedBy)               

        </fieldset>
    }

     <p>
         <input type="submit" value="Submit" />
     </p>

</body>
```

Nothing happened if "submit" button is clicked. I even cold not put a breaking point at the line 
.

Thanks very much for your help.

Hugh

Comment: Hi Brand,

Thanks very much for your help. It was my careless mistake. BTW, I could bot "Vote" your answer. Nothing happened after I clicking the "vote" tab.

Hugh

Comment: No problem. Did you try clicking the checkmark underneath the arrows? That will accept the answer as the solution to your question.

Answer (score 2):

`@Html.BeginForm()` creates a `<form>` element. Right now your submit button is outside of this element, so move it inside.

```
}

 <p>
     <input type="submit" value="Submit" />
 </p>
```

Should be

```
 <p>
     <input type="submit" value="Submit" />
 </p>

} <-- This goes down here
```